# ckeditor not working properly

Tags: php, ckeditor

WHEN saved hum text html codes , always putting IS \ " before any quotes . At the time of preview images for example, does not appear.
example : `src =\"/photos/images/xxx.jpg \" />`
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your database is not adding the quotes automatically ('magic_quotes_gpc' in php configuration)